# How can I test events in angular?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, dom-events

I need to test that events get correctly emitted or broadcast, and trigger events manually.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you're just needing some testing on event firing and catching, this is how I do it. For ensuring that a certain event gets fired (`$emit`-ed or `$broadcast`-ed), a spy is the way to go. You need a reference to the scope that will be calling the `$emit` or `$broadcast`, and then just to do something like this:

```
spyOn(scope, "$emit")
//run code to test
expect(scope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("MY_EVENT_ID", other, possible, args);
```

If you don't need or don't want to worry about the arguments that are passed with the `$emit`, you can put an `$on` on the `$rootScope` and set a flag to know the event was emitted. Something like this:

```
var eventEmitted = false;
$rootScope.$on("MY_EVENT_ID", function() {
   eventEmitted = true;
});
//run code to test
expect(eventEmitted).toBe(true);
```

For testing functionality that runs when an event is caught (`$on`), it's a little easier. Just get a `$rootScope` from the `inject` function and then send the desired event.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("EVENT_TO_TEST", other, possible, args);
//expects for event here
```

Now, I imagine this event handling would be happening in a directive or a controller (or both) For setting up directive tests, see https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing. For setting up controller tests, see https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/test/unit/controllersSpec.js#L27

Comment: This is good for exact matches but how would one match a subset of arguments? For example if the args are just one object {p1:'yes', p2:'no'} how would you expect that p1:'yes' no matter what p2 is (or if it event exists)? I know there's the 'any' jasmine keyboard but that seems to be the opposite - not fine grained enough control. Any middle ground where you can expect just the args you want?

Comment: @LukeMadera Jasmine has `jasmine.objectContaining`. From the docs: jasmine.objectContaining is for those times when an expectation only cares about certain key/value pairs in the actual object.

Comment: Thanks, but would there be a way to use jasmine? Something like: `expect(scope.$emit.calls.argsFor(0)[0]).toBe('MY_EVENT_ID');`

Comment: @dnc253 I have a parent node listening for `$emit` events. My tests pass only when I use `$rootScope.$broadcast` and then check for events, they don't pass for `$rootScope.$emit`, is this because `$emit` can only traverse up the node and not itself and to the children nodes?

Comment: @cameronjroe a bit late, but I believe using `toHaveBeenCalledWith` is suitable even to just check if an event was fired. This is because the event name is an argument for `$emit`, so here the test would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you should follow to $broadcast event in angular JS

While inijecting initialize the rootScope and scope stub as given below:

```
var rootScope;
var scopeStub = beforeEach(function() {
    inject(function($rootScope, _$controller_) {
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        scopeStub = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;
    });
});
```

After controller is created raise event using rootScope like below:

```
rootScope.$broadcast('eventName', parameter1);
```

Answer (score 0):

We used this sintax for A1

```
=========== Controller ========
    var vm = this;
    $scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data){
        console.log('event number', data.id);
    });
============ Test =============
 it('should throw myEvent', function() {
    var data = {};
    $scope.$broadcast('myEvent', {id:1});
    $scope.$broadcast('myEvent', {id:2});
    $scope.$broadcast('myEvent', {id:3});
});

============ Output ============
Chrome LOG: '--------------------------------------------'
Chrome LOG: 'event number', 1
Chrome LOG: 'event number', 2
Chrome LOG: 'event number', 3
```