# How to unit test app.js, $routeProvider, app.config()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

A typical app.js file in angularjs goes like this:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]); // the example is taken from the angularjs tutorial
```

How would you unit test this file?

This is a bit edgy and percentage coverage oriented. Does it make sense to test it in the first place ?
I think yes because when navigating to a certain url, I would like to be sure that the correct route is used.

Note : the question is not only about testing $routeProvider but also regarding app.config().

Thanks!

Comment: this question answers this i think. I had the same question but reformulated it to "testing routeChange events" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093010/jasmine-unit-test-case-for-routechangestart-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to test configuration settings.

Does it make sense to ask that ? Well .. I think that is debatable. I asked myself this question many times. 
How do we make sure that the values we use as configuration are correct ?

I am not sure that calling it "unit testing" is correct, even if the configuration is a fluent configuration.

I think you should not worry about "testing" configuration settings since "testing" configuration would result in redundancy and recursion. Let me further detail what I mean by that. When adding a configuration setting like:

```
when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
```

the only thing to test would be to see that for the route `/phones` you will use the `controller` value `'PhoneDetailCtrl'`. Doing that would not test anything, but merely validate that some string pairs are correct. And that would raise a recursion problem. By "validating" string values how do you know that the person "testing" the configuration is using the correct values ? Shouldn't you test the test too ?

To answer your question from the technical point of view .. how to test that .. I have no idea how to test the configuration of the routeProvider, but I don't think you should do it.

Comment: so, my app.run is in there, too with some routechangestart handlers etc. and I don't like this class bogging down my coverage reports. Actually, (though unlikely) testing the router would ensure that no angular changes are breaking, not just configuration values. Say you upgrade and they called controllerAs to something else? it'd break. Plus, there's the scenario of logic in the handlers like wildcard operator. '/detail/:wildcard*' or specific params.