# How do I test an event has been broadcast in AngularJS?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I am just wondering how can I test the `handleAddClientBroadcast` event?

I have a navigation service like so:

```
angular.module("ruleManagement.services")
    .factory('navigationService', function ($rootScope) {

        var navigationService = {};

        navigationService.prepForBroadcast = function() {
          this.broadCastIsAddClientItem();
        };

        navigationService.broadCastIsAddClientItem = function() {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('handleAddClientBroadcast');
        };

        return navigationService;
    });
```

I inject this navigation service into my `clientsCtrl` and catch the `handleAddClientBroadcast` like so:

```
$scope.$on('handleAddClientBroadcast', function () {
  $scope.clientModel = {
    id: 0,
    name: "",
    description: "",
    rules: []
  };

  var lastClient = _.findLast($scope.clients);

  if (typeof lastClient == 'undefined' || lastClient == null) {
    lastClient = $scope.clientModel;
  }

  $scope.clientModel.id = lastClient.id + 1;
  $scope.clients.push($scope.clientModel);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I found this helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272414/how-can-i-test-events-in-angular

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test $scope.$on in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441782/how-do-i-test-scope-on-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using Jasmine

```
spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').andCallThrough();

...

expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('eventName');
```

Comment: It  later versions of jasmine it is spyOn(scope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();