# How do I test $scope.$on in AngularJS

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-scope

How do I test that the scope is populated after the broadcast? I've searched and found a few QA's here in stackexchange, but none answered my problem. The code is working alright, just don't know how to test it. May I add that I'm a novice to testing, and especially with Jasmine.

So, here's the code:

Service CrappySvc:

```
update: function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('updatecrappy', Crappy.query());
}
```

Controller GetCrappyCtrl:

```
  $scope.$on('updatecrappy', function(event, crap) {
    $scope.crap = crap;
  });
```

Jasmine:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $httpBackend, $controller, Crappy) {
  rootScope = $rootScope;
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  Crappy = mockCrappy;

      ...
  spyOn(rootScope, '$broadcast');
      ...

  ctrl = $controller('GetCrappyCtrl', {
  $scope : scope,
  Crappy : mockCrappy
});
```

}));

```
it('$scope.$on should have been triggered', function() {          
  rootScope.$broadcast('updatecrappy', [{id : 2, name : 'crappy'}]);
  expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('updscenes', [{id : 2, name : 'crappy'}]);
```

});

Stone

Comment: I found this helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272414/how-can-i-test-events-in-angular

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to tell Jasmine to let the spy call the actual $broadcast function

```
spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').andCallThrough();
```

If you don't use `andCallThrough()` the spy does nothing.

[Jasmine Docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>and.callThrough</code>)

**EDIT**

With Jasmine 2, the syntax would be

```
spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();
```

Comment: can we elaborate on what this is actually doing?

Comment: @whitebox That's the thing, it's not really doing much. By default, Jasmine's spies will replace the original function that is being spied on. Calling `and.callThrough()` will add to the default behaviour and cause the spy to *also* call the original function that was being spied on. And that's really all that it does.

Comment: you don't need the and.callThrough() in this case if you are just asserting the broadcast was called

Comment: does mocha have anything like .callThrough

Comment: As far as I know mocha does not come with its own spy-functionality so that would depend on which library you use for mocking.

Comment: This doesn't really test $on.  I have the following in my controller `$scope.$on('myevent', myfunction)`.  I want to spy on `myfunction` and see that it gets called.  I have this `spyOn($scope, 'myfunction'); $rootScope.$broadcast('myevent'); expect($scope.myfunction).toHaveBeenCalled();`  All I get is a screen full of jasmine stack trace with no real error message.

Answer (score 0):

If want to fake the `returnValue` from `$scope.$broadcast()` you can do something like these two cases:

Case 1:

```
scope.$broadcast('TEST_CHANGED', {test: 'test1'});
spyOn(scope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();
expect(something).toEqual('something');
```

Case 2:

```
scope.$broadcast('TEST_CHANGED', {test: 'test2'});
spyOn(scope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();
expect(something2).toEqual('something2');
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as "**toHavebeenCalled**" concerned, there is no need of "**andCallThrough**()". Simple spy would work. In your case your arguments are different.

You are broadcasting  like,
rootScope.$broadcast(**'updatecrappy', [{id : 2, name : 'crappy'}]**);

But you expect :

expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith(**'updscenes', [{id : 2, name : 'crappy'}]);**

look at argument " **updarecrappy**" but in tohavebeencalled it is "**updscenes**".

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sample code below, it works well for me.

Emitting sample event 'onTimeChanged' from $rootScope. My controller has a listener 'onTimeChanged' and I am calling  a method timeChanged() inside it.

```
describe('onTimeChanged()', function() {
    it('should call another method or controller', function() {
        spyOn(searchCtrl, 'timeChanged');
        $rootScope.$emit('onTimeChanged');
        expect(searchCtrl.timeChanged).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Note that I did not spy on method '$emit' of rootScope.