# How can I trigger `$on` events in AngularJS Karma unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am attempting to trigger the `$scope.$on()` method in a controller that is fired when I `$rootScope.broadcast()` an event. I found this question useful: [How can I test events in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272414/how-can-i-test-events-in-angular), but I'm still having trouble detecting an event being broadcast from the `$rootScope` up through a controller's `$scope`.

So far I've managed to test that the `$broadcast` method is called on a corresponding `$rootScope`, but not that the `$on` method was called on a corresponding `$scope` when `$broadcast` is called on the `$rootScope`.

I attempted to `$rootScope.$broadcast` directly in my test, but my spy is not picking up on the event.

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('app.admin.controllers.notes', [])
    .controller('NotesCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.$on('resource-loaded', function(event, resource) { // I want to test this
        $scope.parentType = resource.type;
        $scope.parentId = resource.id;
      });

    });
```

This is my test:

```
describe('The notes controller', function() {

  beforeEach(module('app.admin.controllers.notes'));

  var scope, rootScope, NotesCtrl;

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $injector, $rootScope) {
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    scope = $rootScope.$new(); // I've tried this with and without $new()
    NotesCtrl = $controller('NotesCtrl', {$scope: scope}); // I've tried explicitly defining $rootScope here
  }));

  it('should respond to the `resource-loaded` event', function() {
    spyOn(scope, '$on');
    rootScope.$broadcast('resource-loaded'); // This is what I expect to trigger the `$on` method
    expect(scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

And [here's the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gJcyrhoaXP3U2NSXzoca?p=preview). I've included a passing test of the `$broadcast` method for reference, mainly because I setup the tests in the same manner.

I've read quite a few questions relating to testing events in AngularJS, and it always seems to be a scoping issue. I've heard that in Karma unit testing, `$rootScope` and `$scope` are the same thing, but I'm not really sure what the implication is. I've tried defining the `$rootScope` and the `$scope` as the same object, as well as explicitly injecting the `$rootScope` into the `NotesCtrl` during testing, but nothing makes my test go green.

How can I get the `$on` method in my `NotesCtrl` to fire for this test?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What makes it not working is the fact that you're spying the `$on` function. It works fine when not sying it: http://plnkr.co/edit/hNEj7MmDDKJcJ7b298OB?p=info. And the reason is actually simple. When an event is brodcasted, what is called is not the `$on()` function. What is called is the callback function passed as argument to `$on()` previously: the listener.

Note that, by spying the $on function, you're not testing your code here. All you're trying to test is that when broadcasting en event, child scopes receive it. So you're testing AngularJS itself.

Comment: This is really belated, but for future reference of people who find this, you can test in situations like this by adding .and.callThrough() when creating your spy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
$rootScope.$emit('resource-loaded');
```

Works fine in my tests.

Comment: `$emit` sends the message *up* the scope tree; `$broadcast` goes down.

Answer (score 1):

@kirill.buga

Using $broadcast is right, not $emit because :

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope
>   Dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.

Problem of @ben-harold is trying to spy $on instead of the result of code in the $on.